# how to disable button after page reload in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

My question about jsp and jquery.

How to disable button after refresh page, when I click on button then page reload and button should be disable after reload page.

I  use that functionality when I click on  button then reload page and button must disable. I also  implement this functionality using java and jsp,
Just I need hint how  it possible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. If you want us to help, please provide us some [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A page reload and a page load is the same. Look for [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to remember the page already was loaded... And to decide to disable the button or not.

Comment: You can pass a flag value in Query string during page load. Based on the Querystring flag value you can enable are disable the button in document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Call this jquery after the page reloads

```
$('#btn_id').prop('disabled',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking, I wrote this code untested. But according to documentations if you use [JQuery-Session-Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) you must be able to save events in a session.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="button1">
<input type="button" id="button2">
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        location.reload();
    })

  switch($.session.get("stat")){
    case "":
      $.session.set("stat", "dis");
      $("#button2").prop("disabled",false);
      break;
    case "dis":
      $.session.set("stat", "");
      $("#button2").prop("disabled",true);
      break;
  }


});
```